# How to instantiate a class in Objective-C that don't inherit from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, class, instantiation

Given this:

Person.h:

```
@interface Person 
{
}
- (void) sayHello;
@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person 

- (void)sayHello 
{
    printf("%s", "Steve");
}

@end
```

How do you instantiate the Person? I tried this:

```
Person *p = [Person new];
```

That doesn't work, nor this:

```
Person *p = [Person alloc];
```

[UPDATE]

I forgot to tell, I already tried inheriting from NSObject, the new and alloc works. I'm just curious if we can instantiate a class that doesn't inherit from NSObject?

Comment: What's wrong with `Person` inheriting from `NSObject`?

Comment: +1 as this is a very interesting question, although the practical value might be very few.

Comment: @Costique: Nothing, it's just there are many tutorials I found on web failed to mention that that is a requirement(i.e. inheriting from NSObject). example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/syntax Tried inheriting from Object, but `[Person new]` doesn't work too

Comment: @Hao Most tutorials probably don't mention it because it's kind of a given in object-oriented programming that one inherits from the superclass, and the root class is usually called Object or something like that. Writers of tutorials tend to forget that not everybody knows this fact because it is such a basic thing. Please read (and accept) Josh's answer, it should answer your question thoroughly. If you still have any questions, don't hesitate to comment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You absolutely can do so. Your class simply needs to implement `+alloc` itself, the way that `NSObject` does. At base, this just means using `malloc()` to grab a chunk of memory big enough to fit the structure defining an instance of your class.

Reference-counted memory management would also be nice (`retain`/`release`); this is actually part of the [`NSObject` *protocol*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/). You can adopt the protocol and implement these methods too.

For reference, you can look at [the `Object` class](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/Object.m), which is a root ObjC class like `NSObject`, that Apple provides in its open source repository for the Objective-C runtime:

```
@implementation Object 

// Snip...

+ alloc
{
    return (*_zoneAlloc)((Class)self, 0, malloc_default_zone()); 
}

// ...

- init
{
    return self;
}

// And so on...
```

That being said, you should think of `NSObject` as a integral part of the ObjC runtime. There's little if any reason to implement your own root class outside of curiosity, investigation, or experimentation (which should, however, not be discouraged at all).

Comment: +1 this is absolutely the correct answer.  Really, the *only* time when you wouldn't want to inherit from `NSObject` is when you're going to be doing something *fundamentally different* in terms of memory management.

Comment: A profound answer regarding objective-c which goes beyond: "Click that shiny button in XCode" ... Awesome! +1

Comment: Does this answer also applies for swift?

Comment: No, Swift provides essential class behavior for free.

Answer (score 4):

You must:

1. Inherit from NSObject,
2. Do a "poor man's" class with your own mallocs, etc, or
3. Use Objective-C++ and create a C++ class.

Of course, neither of the other two fit into Objective-C storage management, and their call protocols, etc, are different.

Comment: Almost! For 2, you can simply implement +alloc, -retain, -release, etc... in terms of malloc and your own refcount. By implementing the NSObject *protocol*, you can participate in quite a bit of stuff transparently.

Comment: -1 you don't *have* to inherit from `NSObject`.  There are bunch of classes that don't, such as `NSProxy`.

Comment: @DaveDeLong he means you must *either* do 1. *or* 2. *or* 3.

Answer (score 3):

There is (very likely) no good reason to not want to inherit from NSObject, but there are many good reasons to do so.

I would be curious as to your reason for why you don't want to inherit from NSObject. I would guess it stems from a lack of knowledge rather than a real need.

But even without knowing that reason: Don't do it. It's so hard to do this well in a way that it still plays nice with other Objective-C classes as to be virtually impossible.

Anyway, you're instantiating your objects in a way that hides what's really done. While in Java, you usually create instances via the default constructor method `new`, in Objective-C you instantiate by calling `alloc` on the class and then `init` on the instance:

```
Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
```

(It is *possible* to just use `Person new`, but I wouldn't do it because it hides what's really done from you)

You implement your class such that you inherit from NSObject and then, if necessary, write your own `init` method.

If you want to log to the console, use `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"Hello %@", @"Steven");
```

(`@""` is a special constructor for a NSString. Strings in Objective-C are not byte arrays, but objects.)

Comment: Of course, in Objective-C `new` is just shorthand for vanilla `alloc/init`.

Answer (score -6):

**you can't..**

**Alloc and new ..copy init** all these methods are defined in **NSObject**..

You cannot also create your own since apple does not provide NSObject implementation class..so  you have to inherit from NSObject or its subclass so that you can initialize your class

Comment: of course it is possible. Apple also did it. you "just" have to do your own C-style memory management. NSObject is not a part of the language Objective-C, as isn't Foundation, UIKit, AppKit,…

Comment: I don't understand why you haven't deleted this answer when it's so clearly wrong. Earn yourself a Peer Pressure badge! :)