# how much overhead is put if a class inherit NSObject

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a lightweight c++ class needed to be ported to Objective-C to exploit the facilities provided by NSObject. There will be thousands of instances of the C++ class, and i dont want to add to much overhead by wrapping it in a NSObject derived class.

how big is NSObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should descend from `NSObject`. There is no tangible benefit to not doing so. `NSObject` adds nothing in terms of storage over the lowest level representation of a class but adds an awful lot of behaviour that will allow your classes to act correctly with the runloop, with the normal collections (eg, `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) and with just about everything else.

To answer your question specifically:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

...

NSLog(@"obj size: %zd", class_getInstanceSize([NSObject class]));
```

Outputs '4' on iOS and '8' on 64-bit OS X. So the answer you're looking for is 'the natural size of an integer'. `NSProxy` is the same size, `UIView` (on iOS) is 84 bytes.

Documentation for `class_getInstanceSize` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getInstanceSize) — it explicitly returns "[t]he size in bytes of instances of the class cls", as the name says.

Comment: thats exactly what i want to know.

Answer (score 2):

in the apple documentation it says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that

> The root class of all Objective-C classes is NSObject, which is part
>   of the Foundation framework. All objects in a Cocoa or Cocoa Touch
>   application ultimately inherit from NSObject. This class is the
>   primary access point whereby other classes interact with the
>   Objective-C runtime

So I'd say that every objective-c class ultimately derives from NSObject anyway, so you have no choice. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

**EDIT:**
What I've learned now is that NSObject is *one root class*, which implements the basic behaviour expected from every objective-c class. So basically you could write an objective-c class which implements the protocol of NSObject (I think that is objective-c speak for interface) and implement basic stuff like `alloc` and `init` yourself. Be sure to check out this thread: [How to instantiate a class in Objective-C that don't inherit from NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954075/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-objective-c-that-dont-inherit-from-nsobject)

**EDIT:**
Some more [insight into root classes in objective-c](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/RootClass), very interesting!

Comment: Wrong. not all derives from NSObject.here is one other root class https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `NSObject` is explicitly what all user-defined classes are meant to inherit from and it's what 99.99% of Apple's classes inherit from. The big exception is `NSProxy`, but I don't think that caveat is very helpful to answering the question.

Comment: without knowing anything of the OP's code, there is no helpful answering anyway. maybe this c++ classes have there own memory management and it wouldnt be a good idea to wrap them with objects, that must have the NSObject-protocol's memory management methods implemented.

Comment: some digging in root classes, just for curiosity: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/RootClass

Comment: *disclaimer*: I didnt contribue to that article.

Comment: @vikingosegundo No offense, just wanted to make clear that you provided the link ;)